# Indecomposable module with $\operatorname{End}(M)$ non-commutative

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $A$ be commutative $k$-algebra over a field $k$, and $M$ be a finite dimensional indecomposable* $A$-module. In general, $\operatorname{End}_A(M)/J(\operatorname{End}_A(M))$ will be a division ring $D$. I struggle to find a convincing example where $D$ (or $\operatorname{End}_A(M)$) is not commutative itself. At best, I would like to find such an example for $M$ an $n$-graded module over $A=k[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$. This yields to the following

**Question:** Can a finite dimensional $n$-graded indecomposable $k[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$-module have a non-commutative endomorphism ring? Can its quotient by its radical be non-commutative? If not, can it have any endomorphism ring other than $k$?

**Edit:** Originally, I had asked for a simple module, which cannot be, as pointed out by Eric Wolfsey.

**Edit:** See this [more structured question](/questions/3226938/endomorphism-rings-of-indecomposable-modules) which also incorporates this one.

Answer (score 1):

A simple module is in particular cyclic (generated by any nonzero element), which means every endomorphism of it is given by multiplying by some element of $A$.  So since $A$ is commutative, the endomorphism ring is commutative (specifically, it is the quotient of $A$ by the ideal that annihilates $M$).

In the case that $M$ is additionally $n$-graded over $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, the story is even simpler.  Let $I$ be the idea $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$.  If you fix any nonzero homogeneous element $m\in M$, then $Im$ is a proper submodule of $M$ (it cannot contain $m$, since all its elements have higher degree than $m$).  So by simplicity, $Im=0$.  That means every $x_i$ acts by $0$ on $M$, and so any $k$-vector subspace of $M$ is also a submodule, so by simplicity $M$ is $1$-dimensional (and its endomorphism ring is $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/I\cong k$).

Comment: Thank you. I am sorry for having asked such a stupid question; probably I was not totally clear what I actually want to know. How are things in case of *indecomposable* modules?